# why initializationSettings.iOS is coming as null if i run the flutter app in my ios device + flutter + Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

im newly working on flutter firebase notifications in iOS devices, im not having much idea about it.

we already did the code configuration for android to get the push notification,
same now i want to get the push notification to iOS device.

But when i run the flutter app im getting the initializationSettings.iOS as null and getting the exceptional error, like below

[image]

ive added the APNs key to my firebase cloud messaging and in xcode ive also enabled the push notifications and background modes

Is there any way to resolve this issue asap?.